# Angular - Update <input> value on 'enter' keypress - And work in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm wanting to control the updates of `<input>` values to the 'enter' keypress. (I also update when they leave the field - but that's not the problematic part)

There's a number of answers showing how to use:

```
 '<input ng-model-options="{updateOn : 'change blur'}" [...] />
```

Which does work in Chrome & Firefox - **But not in IE** (11, in my testing). (In theory - the `change` event should cover the enter keypress).

**My question:** Is there a different set of events I can bind to? I'ave made [a Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hCAxnClv68Dl5c06Brm?p=preview) to show/verify the issue.

I'm unsure if IE simply doesn't fire the `change` event (when pressing enter), I have the wrong events, or if it's a bug in Angular.

(Note: At the time of writing, this is Angular 1.4.3)

Comment: You could trigger change event manually by tracking keydown event with keycode 13. This can be done in another directive.

Comment: I'd like to see if it's caused by the browser event implementation (or Angular bug) first. Older answers do show a directive implementation, but point out that was the 'old way' of handling things (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534290/update-angularjs-ng-model-only-on-keypress-enter)

Comment: `{updateOn : 'change blur'}` will update your model on `change` and `blur` events. There is no meaning for enter keypress. So if you want to submit something on enter, then you should do it manually by tracking keypresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this behaviour by creating a directive called `updateOnEnter` and then adding this attribute to your HTML element. This code works in all major browsers.

```
<input id="search_input" type="text" update-on-enter ng-model="filter.search_terms">

angular.module('app').directive('updateOnEnter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind("keyup", function(ev) {
                if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
                    ctrl.$commitViewValue();
                    scope.$apply(ctrl.$setTouched);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```