# AngularJS ng-repeat filter not updating on keypress only on enter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I have a ng-repeater and a textbox which filters this repeater. I want the filter to happen as you type at the moment it works when you press enter or tab off the search textbox. I thought this was the default behavior but it does not seem to work, not sure if there is a browser setting or something?

The code is as follows

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.filterText" />
<div ng-repeat="product in vm.products | filter: vm.filterText">
```

Where vm is my bound view model

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534290/update-angularjs-ng-model-only-on-keypress-enter

Comment: this is the opposite of what i want...

Comment: Its currently not working on keypress, even though i did not expressly restrict it

Comment: Can you give an example of what your models look like (`vm.products`)?

Comment: Does this work for you https://jsfiddle.net/a19hdtvp/ ? As I write the filter, the result changes.

Comment: id int, Name  string, Price decimal, Createddate Date, Type enum, modifieddate date

Comment: Hi Juan yes that worked on fiddler so must be something else in my html or controller that is doing it. It is strange that it works on enter though

Comment: when i plug your code into my app it stops working haha, must be something to do with how i setup my viewmodel or my use of $scope